# Return a substring between two characters in PHP

Tags: php, substring

As the title says I need to return a particular part of string that falls between two substrings.

Example:

```
$string = numbergrid_21372566/_assets/audio/
```

Now every time, I need to return the part of string that falls between the last two slashes (/) I.E **audio** in this case.

How can I achieve that? 
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) method to split string from given characters, then use [list](https://www.php.net/list) to match the element you want:

```
list(,,$var,) = explode('/', $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
$parts = explode("/", $string);
$res = $parts[count($parts)-2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$string = 'numbergrid_21372566/_assets/audio/';
$output = explode('/', $string)[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = explode('/',$string);
$firstSegment = $arr[0]; // numbergrid_21372566
$secondSegment = $arr[1]; // _assets
$thirdSegment = $arr[2]; // audio
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) method, combined with the [strpos](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) method:

```
$start = strpos($string, "/");
$end = strpos($string, "/", $start);
$length = $end - $start;
$result = substr($string, $start, $length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it always would be the last part, you can use array_pop function:

```
$arr = explode('/', $string);
$result = array_pop($arr);
```